# Mock requests in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

I have this function:

```
def function_to_test(..):
    # some stuff

    response = requests.post("some.url", data={'dome': 'data'})

    # some stuff with response
```

I want to make a test, but **mocking** *requests.post("some.url", data={'dome': 'data'})* because I know it works. I need something like:

```
def my tets():

    patch('requests.post', Mock(return_value={'some': 'values'})).start()

    # test for *function_to_test*
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

**Edited**

I found these ways:

```
class MockObject(object):
        status_code = 200
        content = {'some': 'data'}

    # First way
    patch('requests.post', Mock(return_value=MockObject())).start()

    # Second way
    import requests
    requests.post = Mock(return_value=MockObject())
```

Are these approaches good? which one is better? another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continue testing and testing I prefer to use this to mock requests. Hope it helps others.

```
class MockObject(object):
    status_code = 200
    content = {'some': 'data'}

patch('requests.post', Mock(return_value=MockObject())).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTPretty(https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty), a library made just for that kind of mocks.

Comment: +1 because it looks nice but I don't want external apps now. I'll maybe use it later. Thanks

Comment: This does *not* answer the question. They want to patch the requests module directly, not monkey-patch the socket library (which is what HTTPretty does).

Comment: Actually, http://github.com/dropbox/responses was specifically made to patch `requests`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flexmock for that. see the example below

Say you have function in file `./myfunc.py`

```
# ./myfunc.py
import requests

def function_to_test(..):
  # some stuff
  response = requests.post("www.google.com", data={'dome': 'data'})
  return response
```

Then the testcase is in `./test_myfunc.py`

```
# ./test_myfunc.py
import flexmock as flexmock
import myfunc

def test_myfunc():
  (flexmock(myfunc.requests).should_recieve("post").with_args("www.google.com", data={"dome":
   "data"}).and_return({'some': 'values'}))

  resp = myfunc.function_to_test()
  assert resp["some"] == "values"
```

Try this, see if this works or let me know for more enhancement/improvement.